# ActiveRecord SQL variable substitution

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to write this:

```
post_view.id = 1

Comment.find(:all, :conditions => "post_parent_id = 'post_view.id'").size
```

The second statement does not work because that is not an appropriate way to write `post_view.id` .

Anyoone know the proper syntax?

Comment: Is `post_view` a pre-existing variable that you're not showing us? I don't understand the first line, or what you're trying to do. `Comment.find(:all, :conditions => ["post_parent_id = ?", post_view.id]).size` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
post_view.id = 1
Comment.find(:all, :conditions => ["post_parent_id = ?", post_view.id]).size
```